# Crash when i update a TableView firing an Event

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have a tabbed Android App like this:

[image]

The first two Tabs contains empty Views, the third contains a tableview.

I added to it an eventlistener (on a custom event) and I update his content in real time each time the event is fired.

```
var tb;

function update(){  
    tb.setData([]); 
    var row = [];
    var r = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow();   
    row.push(r);
    tb.setData(row);    
    return true;
}

function MainView() {

    self = new ui.View();

    tb = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
          scrollable: false,
          showVerticalScrollIndicator: false,
          top: 10,
          width: "98%",
          //height: perH(0.95) - baseH,
          border: 1,
          borderColor: "gray",
          borderRadius: 6,
    });
    self.add(tb);
    // And i add an event listener to call the update function
    Ti.App.addEventListener( 'updateFav', update );   
    return self;
}   
module.exports = MainView;
```

Each time I fire the event the tableview is updated normally and everything works well.

But if i tap the first tab, and go to the second or third, the app crashes! "Has stopped" is the message that Android shows.

The logcat says "NullPointer exception" but i dont know why!

Again: The problem occurs simply changing the current tab form first to second or third! The problem not occurs changing only from second to third or viceversa!!!!

Any suggestion?

This is the error:

```
[WARN][dalvikvm( 2070)] threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1f48648)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)] (main) [42854,169668] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.NullPointerException; Titanium 3.1.3,2013/09/18 12:01,222f4d1
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:318)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3264)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:448)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiImageView.<init>(TiImageView.java:63)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIImageView.<init>(TiUIImageView.java:94)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.ImageViewProxy.createView(ImageViewProxy.java:43)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:452)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:438)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.forceCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:406)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableViewRowProxyItem.createControls(TiTableViewRowProxyItem.java:246)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableViewRowProxyItem.setRowData(TiTableViewRowProxyItem.java:408)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableViewRowProxyItem.setRowData(TiTableViewRowProxyItem.java:90)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableView$TTVListAdapter.getView(TiTableView.java:229)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableView.onLayout(TiTableView.java:572)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.onLayout(TiCompositeLayout.java:578)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1388)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.onLayout(TiCompositeLayout.java:578)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.onLayout(TiCompositeLayout.java:578)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.onLayout(TiCompositeLayout.java:578)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 2070)]   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.j
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:318)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3264)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:448)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiImageView.<init>(TiImageView.java:63)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIImageView.<init>(TiUIImageView.java:94)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at ti.modules.titanium.ui.ImageViewProxy.createView(ImageViewProxy.java:43)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:452)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:438)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.forceCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:406)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableViewRowProxyItem.createControls(TiTableViewRowProxyItem.java:246)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableViewRowProxyItem.setRowData(TiTableViewRowProxyItem.java:408)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableViewRowProxyItem.setRowData(TiTableViewRowProxyItem.java:90)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableView$TTVListAdapter.getView(TiTableView.java:229)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableView.onLayout(TiTableView.java:572)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.onLayout(TiCompositeLayout.java:578)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1388)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.onLayout(TiCompositeLayout.java:578)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.onLayout(TiCompositeLayout.java:578)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.onLayout(TiCompositeLayout.java:578)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 2070)]  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(C
```

Comment: I would recommend trying to put log statements in the update method and the MainView() methods to see the order things are getting called. In the update method, try printing out the value of tb before anything runs.